# Converting parametric equations to xy equation

Tags: calculus

I have these parametric equations:
$$
x=1+t \\
y=1-t
$$

How do I make this to the xy equation?

- David

Comment: So the xy equation is just eliminate t and end up with x=2-y??????

Comment: Converting a parametric set of coordinate equations to a single Cartesian equation doesn't always work.  When it does, you can write the parameter t  in terms of one of the coordinate variables, and then insert it into the other coordinate equation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Use the first equation to find an expression for $t$ in terms of $x$.
- Substitute into the second equation to get an equation only involving $x$ and $y$.
- Rearrange if desired.

---

**Update:** This method will work for the example you gave, but might not work for a general example.  For example, the following is a particularly common parametrization:

\begin{align}
x &= \cos t \\
y &= \sin t
\end{align}

Here, you can't get a unique expression for $t$ in terms of $x$: for example, if $x$ is $1$, we could have $t=0$ or $t=2\pi$.  In this case, the solution is to square both equations to give:

\begin{align}
x^2&=\cos^2 t\\
y^2&=\sin^2 t
\end{align}

Then add them together to get

$$
x^2+y^2=\cos^2t+\sin^2t=1
$$

This equation ($x^2+y^2=1$) is the equation for a circle of radius $1$ about $(0,0)$.

---

**Edit:** (*answering the question in comment below*) Sometimes you're presented with a parametrization like

\begin{align}
x&=1+t\\
y&=1-t
\end{align}

and you want to convert that into a vector equation.  A mathematician would immediately recognize that system of parametric equations as a vector equation: $x$ and $y$ are themselves coordinates of the vector $\begin{pmatrix}
x\\ 
y
\end{pmatrix}$.  The equations then become:

$$
\vec{r}=\begin{pmatrix}x \\ y\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1+t\\1-t\end{pmatrix}
$$

and you can rearrange that into whatever (vector) form you like using the usual rules for addition of vectors.

Comment: I was not sure it was that simple. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes, it's pretty simple, though it can get harder for more complicated equations.

Comment: What if I want to put them in the position vector form? not just [1+t, 1-t] but R(t) = R0+tv?

Answer (score 3):

$\text{AD}$$\text{D}$ $\text{EM}$.

Answer (score 0):

$x = 1 + t
\\y = 1 - t 
\\x = -(1- t) + 2 
\\x = 2 - y  $